# Jensen's inequality and independent random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $s$ be a zero-mean random variable and $s'$ an independent copy of $s$. Let $q\ge 1$. Why is it true that $\mathbb{E}[|s|^q] \le \mathbb{E}[|s-s'|^q]$? Remark: If $q=2$, i can see why the inequality is true, since the RHS can be expanded, from which it is seen that it is twice the LHS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $s$ and $s'$ are independent,  $E(s-s'|s)=s-E(s')=s$

Conditional Jensen inequality yields $$|s|^q = |E(s-s'|s)|^q\leq E(|s-s'|^q|s)$$

Taking expectations, $$E(|s|^q) \leq E(|s-s'|^q)$$

Comment: Very elegant...